# Item Limit inside SharePoint 2007 List set to Unlimited - possible?

Tags: 2007, list, list-view

Is it possible to set the 'Item Limit' option to Unlimited? (Currently, there are only 2 options 
[1] Display items in batches of the specified size.
[2] Limit the total number of items returned to the specified amount
For MOSS 2007 List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a better option than just putting an insanely huge number there.  But this is clearly not recommended...

Take a look at the [SharePoint Boundaries](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787%28office.12%29.aspx) on TechNet ? You should, as it is stated :

> Item
>   2,000 per view
>   Testing indicates a reduction in performance beyond two thousand items. Using indexing on a flat folder view can improve performance.

For the display part of the data, it is better to stick to those binairies.  To query data, there are other ways to do it (using CAML query, SPSiteDataQuery, Search API, etc.)

Comment: Hi Sebastien, the reason for doing this is because when I used SPServices to retrieve all records, it always display the first batches (which is limited by the SharePoint View.) Unless I can set SPServices to ignore the View limitation, the only option left will be to set 'Item Limit' option unlimited. Please let me know if there are still other ways for me to get SPServices to retrieve all the List items without any restriction. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know well the SPServices library, but I know that you can page your query with the web services... Would it be possible to do it with SPServices ? The paging functionnalities let you get a subset of the records and provides you the token to pass for your next query, to get the next page.  Could it be a solution ?

Comment: I wish to retrieve all the records instead of viewing them as batches.